# Why to use SparkSession in the beginning of Notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am pretty new to Spark and my question might be an absurd one.

We can create a dataframe using **spark.createDataFrame(data)** and can execute SQL commands using **spark.sql('select 1')** without even calling the **SparkSession.builder.appName('SomeName').getOrCreate()**

[image]

Then why do we need to call SparkSession.builder...?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is only in a Databricks notebook, so that the user can not override any parameters that already have been set, since Spark is already running on a cluster.

If you are running a .jar or Python wheel, you still need to create the SparkSession explicitly.

Comment: FYI, this behavior is not just in databricks notebooks. I've seen that cdsw and aws sagemaker notebooks can be configured by the admins to such a specification.